# Specifying which concrete type to retrieve

Tags: structuremap

I am looking at structuremap as an IOC/DI tool. Looking at this example:

http://docs.structuremap.net/QuickStart.htm

The only thing that does not make sense is, if I have an interface and derive several concrete types from it, in the code:

public class ClassThatGetsAnIValidator
    {
        public void SaveObject(object objectToSave)
        {
            // Go get the proper IValidator from StructureMap
            IValidator validator = ObjectFactory.GetInstance();

```
        var notification = validator.Validate(objectToSave);
        if (notification.IsValid())
        {
            // save the object
        }
    }
}
```

How do I know which validator I get? IE I may have an AlphaBetValidator, NumericValidator, etc, with different method bodys and so on.....

I think this is the point:

Registering "what" and "how" StructureMap should build or find those requested services (the tedious part, but it's gotten much better over the years)

Which I struggle to grasp.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://docs.structuremap.net/RetrievingServices.htm):

> If there is only one Instance for a registered PluginType, that
>   Instance will be assumed to be the default for the PluginType. 
>   Otherwise, if there is more than one Instance for a PluginType,
>   StructureMap must be explicitly told which Instance is the default,
>   otherwise the call to GetInstance() will throw an exception (202).

To resolve to a particular instance you could use the naming mechanism. From the same documentation page:

> Sometimes it's advantageous to retrieve a "named" instance of a type. 
>   Let's say that you're building a system that needs to connect to
>   interface with multiple external shipping systems.  You've designed an
>   interface for your system called IShippingSystem that hides the
>   details of each external shipping behind adapters.  The rest of your
>   code should only "know" how to interact with the IShippingSystem, but
>   at some point, some class needs to know how to select and retrieve the
>   proper instance of IShippingSystem.  Before the advent of IoC
>   containers like StructureMap, you would have coded a Factory class and
>   possibly a Builder class by hand to do the construction.  With
>   StructureMap, this code is simply a call to the
>   ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance(Type, string) method.

```
IShippingService internationalService = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IShippingService>("International");

IShippingService domesticService = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IShippingService>("Domestic");
```